# Secure more my register form

Tags: php, forms, security, encryption

I want to make the following form more secure using bcrypt or something like that.

I am newbie to PHP, so take it slow and do not expect me to understund "don't use ..., use ...." without explanation.

Futhermore, i searched to Google for some forms tutorials but nothing found with encryption like bcrypt, hash256/512 etc.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);  
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);  
ini_set('display_errors',1);
require_once 'database.php';

    $Username   =   $_POST['username']; #Username
    $Password   =   $_POST['password']; #Password
    $Password2  =   $_POST['password2'];#Password

if(empty(Password2)){ 
    echo "Please enter a valid confirmation password.";
    $msg .=" Please enter a valid confirmation password."; 
    echo 
            "<script>
            alert('$msg');
            window.location.href='../register.html';
            </script>";
            exit;
} 

if($Password !== Password2){ 
        echo "Sorry, passwords do not match!";
        $msgPass = "Sorry, passwords do not match!";
        echo 
            "<script>
            alert('$msgPass');
            window.location.href='../register.html';
            </script>";
            exit;
}



function NewUser()
{
    global $Username,$Password;
    #Egxwrish stoixeiwn
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES ('$Username','$Password')";
    $data = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if($data)
    {
        return "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED...";
    }
}

function SignUp()
{
    global $Username,$Password;
    if(!empty($Username))   //checking the 'username' name which is from register.html, if is it empty or have some text
        {
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$Username'");

            if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $msg = NewUser();
                echo $msg;
            }
            else {
                echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER...!";
                die(mysql_error());
            }

        }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //User registration
    SignUp();
    echo "Your account has been created successfully. \\n Thank you for joined us!";
    $msgSuccess = "Your account has been created successfully. \\n Thank you for joined us!";
        echo 
            "<script>
            alert('$msgSuccess');
            window.location.href='../index.php';
            </script>";

}
?>
```

Comment: I don't know how you didn't find anything reliable. Here is the official documentation of password_hash(), if you didn't know about it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still using the deprecated MySQL. Consider using MySQLi or PDO instead. If you need it super secure, consider below instead. If you find it tough (its not but still if you face difficulties in understanding this), then first read some basics about PDO or MySQLi. Consider PHP 5.5 or later too.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

```
<?php
// require_once 'database.php'; Consider PDO in your database.php like below

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbhost=dbhost;dbname=dbname', 'dbuser', 'dbpass'); // Provide your own credentials

    $Username   =   $_POST['username']; #Username
    $Password   =   $_POST['password']; #Password
    $Password2  =   $_POST['password2'];#Password

if(empty(Password2)){ 
    echo "Please enter a valid confirmation password.";
    $msg .=" Please enter a valid confirmation password."; 
    echo 
            "<script>
            alert('$msg');
            window.location.href='../register.html';
            </script>";
            exit;
} 

if($Password !== $Password2){ 
        echo "Sorry, passwords do not match!";
        $msgPass = "Sorry, passwords do not match!";
        echo 
            "<script>
            alert('$msgPass');
            window.location.href='../register.html';
            </script>";
            exit;
}



function NewUser()
{
    global $Username,$Password;
    #Egxwrish stoixeiwn
    $hashed_pass = PASSWORD_HASH($Password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
    $data = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $data->execute(array(':username'=>$Username, ':password'=>$hashed_pass));
    if($data->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        return "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED...";
    }
}

function SignUp()
{
    global $Username,$Password;
    if(!empty($Username))   //checking the 'username' name which is from register.html, if is it empty or have some text
        {
                $query = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
                $query = $pdo->prepare($query);
                $query->execute(array(':username'=>$Username));
                if($query->rowCount() == 0)
            {
                $msg = NewUser();
                echo $msg;
            }
            else {
                echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER...!";
                die();
            }

        }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //User registration
    SignUp();
    echo "Your account has been created successfully. \\n Thank you for joined us!";
    $msgSuccess = "Your account has been created successfully. \\n Thank you for joined us!";
        echo 
            "<script>
            alert('$msgSuccess');
            window.location.href='../index.php';
            </script>";

}
?>
```

Comment: I already convert database to mysqli. Should stay with mysqli or use PDO instead? By the way,propably the best anwser that someone could give me!  

The code now is below but i am getting blank page :/
Link: http://pastebin.com/9EP6bWfR

Comment: It depends on your own choice. Both MySQLi and PDO are valid. Use prepared statements for db queries. Regarding the blank page, a mix of different types of coding style may be the reason behind this. Choose one and go for it. Either MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You are letting users know that someone else is already registered. This is called user enumeration. Depending on your business, this could be a vulnerability.

It's better to ask for email address only. If email exists in your db, send them an email, saying "hey, someone is trying to register with your email". If the user does not exist, send them an email with a link to step 2 to continue registration.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. This is a website just for some friends and I don't think I need to spend a lot of time developing something like this. The amateur way is fine for what kind they want it for ;)